# Big-O for a compiler

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction

Does anyone have insight into the typical big-O complexity of a compiler?

I know it must be `>= n` (where n is the number of lines in the program), because it needs to scan each line at least once.

I believe it must also be `>= n.logn` for a procedural language, because the program can introduce O(n) variables, functions, procedures, and types etc., and when these are referenced within the program it will take O(log n) to look up each reference.

Beyond that my very informal understanding of compiler architecture has reached its limits and I am not sure if forward declarations, recursion, functional languages, and/or other tricks will increase the algorithmic complexity of the compiler.

So, in summary:

1. For a 'typical' procedural language (C, pascal, C#, etc.) is there a limiting big-O for an efficiently designed compiler (as a measure of number of lines)
2. For a 'typical' functional language (lisp, Haskell, etc.) is there a limiting big-O for an efficiently designed compiler (as a measure of number of lines)

Comment: Number of lines is not a precise indicator of the amount of work to be done. A piece of code can be golfed into a single line and have the complexity of ungolfed version that is hundred of lines.

Comment: Why do you assume it would take O(log n) to look up the reference to a given variable/function/type name?

Comment: Agree, using hash table can look it up in O(1)

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" as a compiler consists of many parts, each may have a different complexity, and each may differ between compilers.

Comment: @Dukeling "Too broad" does not mean "involves some moving parts" it means "too large a subject to cover in Q&A format", and I think the latter does not necessarily apply. There are literally thousands of good questions about compilers where answers need to at least touch on the major phases of compilation. Are those too broad too?

Comment: Scanning and parsing are both O(N) unless incompetently implemented. Symbol table lookup is O(1) ditto. AST processing if any, optimization if any, register allocation if any, and code generation can be anything from O(N) onwards depending on internal complexity.

Comment: @delnan It would just be silly to say **all** such questions are too broad, but I think this particular one is. I think a great answer to this question would be quite a few pages long - it wouldn't just say "the complexity of this part is X", but rather explain what exactly that part does, and how the complexity of X can be obtained in sufficient detail. In addition, it would probably have to pick a language for this said complexity and discuss the chosen language in sufficient detail to be able to understand the answer for someone not familiar with it.

Comment: Indeed, this question is ill-posed but there is an interesting question in here somewhere. Lexical and syntactic analysis of C# is O(n) in the number of characters but semantic analysis can be much harder because it is possible to encode problems into the program that the compiler must solve. C#, for example, is NP-HARD to analyze because it is possible to encode 3SAT problems that the overload resolution algorithm must demonstrate a solution to. I demonstrate how here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx

Comment: Moreover, any language that has a combination of nominal subtyping, and covariant/contravariant generic types could be *undecidable* depending on the exact details of the language; the decidability of some languages is still an open question. See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/FOOL2007.pdf for details.

Comment: I am curious why you believe that it takes O(lg n) to look up a string. It takes O(1) to look up a string in a hash table **in the side of a hash table**, but it takes O(n) to look up a string in a hash table **in the length of the string**.

Comment: Oh, one other: in C# the method type inference algorithm is typically n squared in the number of type arguments to be inferred but there is a rare worst case in which it is n to the fourth. Since the number of type arguments to be inferred is in practice never more than five or six, this is irrelevant. (I could have written the implementation to be n squared always, but that would have been a huge amount of work for absolutely no practical gain.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is unanswerable in it's current form. The complexity of a compiler certainly wouldn't be measured in lines of code or characters in the source file. This would describe the complexity of the parser or lexer, but no other part of the compiler will ever even touch that file.

After parsing, everything will be in terms of various AST's representing the source file in a more structured manner. A compiler will have **a lot** of intermediate languages, each with it's own AST. The complexity of various phases would be in terms of the size of the AST, which doesn't correlate at all to the character count or even to the previous AST necessarily.

Consider this, we can parse most languages in linear time to the number of characters and generate some AST. Simple operations such as type checking are generally `O(n)` for a tree with `n` leaves. But then we'll translate this AST into a form with potentially, double, triple or even exponentially more nodes then on the original tree. Now we again run single pass optimizations on our tree, but this might be `O(2^n)` relative to the original AST and lord knows what to the character count!

I think you're going to find it quite impossible to even find what `n` should be for some complexity `f(n)` for a compiler.

As a nail in the coffin, compiling some languages is undecidable including java, C# and Scala (it turns out that nominal subtyping + variance leads to undecidable typechecking). Of course C++'s templating system is turing complete which makes decidable compilation equivalent to the halting problem (undecidable). Haskell + some extensions is undecidable. And many others that I can't think of off the top of my head. There is no worst case complexity for these languages' compilers.

Comment: What kind of AST transformation causes exponential blowup in the number of leaves? That'd make even very modest programs completely impractical to compile. In my expeirence, the size of the AST and the intermediate language programs will be roughly proportional to the size of the input file. Depending on the details of the program the AST may be larger or smaller (e.g. when expanding syntactic sugar), with potentially large constant factors, but I don't think you can meaningfully expand the AST to size O(n log n), let alone worse.

Comment: How is compiling Java and C# undecidable? I'll buy that Scala's type system is turing complete (though whether "compiling it is undecidable" is the correct term is up for debate), but Java and C# are positively tame.

Comment: @delnan It lies in variance. Ben Pierce and Andrew Kennedy have a [paper on it](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1714&context=cis_papers) (which also pops up with a simple google btw :)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I've come across that before. Still, "there is no 'reasonable complexity'" is a very fishy conclusion.

Comment: @delnan Also, inlining in small programs is at least `O(n^2)`. This is a worse case complexity measure so we're supposed to examine the pathological cases :)

Comment: @delnan If something is undecidable, there isn't a complexity for it since it loops forever. If you want a complexity for a correct compiler for these languages, there isn't one.

Comment: @delnan I'm assuming you're the downvoter, nothing in the answer is incorrect so I'm curious why the downvote.

Comment: It's simply not a useful statement. Yes, it might loop indefinitely, but that's not the cases we're interested in when asking for the performance of a compiler. I downvoted primarily to counter the upvote while I still have my doubts about the core points of this answer being useful in the context of this answer.

Comment: @delnan It's exactly what we're interested in when we're examing the `O` of a compiler, which is the **worst** possible complexity. The answer asked for the worst case complexity of "a compiler". Even taking generously to mean "a reasonable language" there isn't a worst case complexity. In any arbitrary compiler this question is also absurd. And even given a compiler for a trivial language like STLC you're still at the mercy of whatever optimizations/transformations you have to run. For example register allocation is `O(2^n)`.

Comment: (You're conflating the kind of bound with the case for which the bound applies. But anyway:) That the problem is undecidable is interesting, but the complexity of those instances which *are* decidable (however they may be distinguished) is also of interest. Given that the undecidability was discovered by theory rather than actual programs, it's also the metric more likely to be significant in practice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46794/discussion-between-delnan-and-jozefg)

Comment: Large programs wouldn't compile if the complexity were exponential. Since enterprise systems are able to execute code, it implies they use more efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Reaching back to what I can remember from my compilers class... some of the details here may be a bit off, but the general gist should be pretty much correct.

Most compilers actually have multiple phases that they go through, so it'd be useful to narrow down the question somewhat. For example, the code is usually run through a *tokenizer* that pretty much just creates objects to represent the smallest possible units of text. `var x = 1;` would be split into tokens for the var keyword, a name, an assignment operator, and a literal number, followed by a statement finalizer (';'). Braces, parentheses, etc. each have their own token type.

The tokenizing phase is roughly O(n), though this can be complicated in languages where keywords can be contextual. For example, in C#, words like `from` and `yield` can be keywords, but they could also be used as variables, depending on what's around them. So depending on how much of that sort of thing you have going on in the language, and depending on the specific code that's being compiled, just this first phase could conceivably have O(n²) complexity. (Though that would be highly uncommon in practice.)

After tokenizing, then there's the parsing phase, where you try to match up opening/closing brackets (or the equivalent indentations in some languages), statement finalizers, and so forth, and try to make sense of the tokens. This is where you need to determine whether a given name represents a particular method, type, or variable. A wise use of data structures to track what names have been declared within various scopes can make this task pretty much O(n) in most cases, but again there are exceptions.

In one video I saw, Eric Lippert said that correct C# code can be compiled in the time between a user's keystrokes. But if you want to provide meaningful error and warning messages, then the compiler has to do a great deal more work.

After parsing, there can be a number of extra phases including optimizations, conversion to an intermediate format (like byte code), conversion to binary code, just-in-time compilation (and extra optimizations that can be applied at that point), etc. All of these *can* be relatively fast (probably O(n) most of the time), but it's such a complex topic that it's hard to answer the question even for a single language, and practically impossible to answer it for a genre of languages.

Comment: If lexing is O(n²), someone didn't do their job - either the compiler writer (by being actively stupid about implementing it) or the language designer (by making a highly ambigiuous language). Non-regular lexical featues such as contextual keywords (which I would always lex as keyword and sort out uses as identifiers during parsing) or significant whitespace (indentation stack) *can* be resolved with a little bit of extra on-line maintaince, leaving complexity at O(n). Many optimizations, on the other hand, *do* have worse-than-linear complexity in practice.

Comment: "C# code can be compiled in the time between a user's keystrokes" In C# or Java, you have the luxury of skipping most of the optimizations, because you can always rely on the JIT compiler to kick in during run time. For "real" compiled languages, the time needed for optimization probably dominates the parsing time by a large margin (I think most of these have near-linear runtime in practice as well, but could break down on certain artificial input instances).

Comment: @NiklasB. Luckily, for use cases where you need to react to keystrokes, you either don't need to generate code *at all* (intellisense, catching errors) or don't need any optimizations (debugging). Also, compiling C++ does not only take time because it targets machine code, language design plays a significant part.

Comment: @delnan: Sure, Go is a perfect example to show that you can have good code in short time.

Comment: I note that Roslyn has to be very clever about skipping all unnecessary work in order to achieve the performance goal of analysis between keystrokes. The Roslyn lexer and parser were both designed carefully to ensure that they only re-lex and re-parse the portion of the program that actually changed on the last keystroke, so that previous analysis can be re-used.  Similarly the semantic analysis is very "lazy"; if you type `foo.` then only the parts of the program necessary to work out "what does `foo` mean and what are its members?" are analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

As fas as i know:
It depends on the type of parser the compiler uses in it's parsing step.
The main type of parsers are LL and LR, and both have different complexities.

Comment: The parsing is just one small part of a compiler. Regardless, any decent parser is linear time, so this doesn't give much insight. LR is always linear time, LL if it's based on lookahead rather than backtracking, and likewise for most other practical options. Parsing won't be the bottleneck, asymptotically speaking (constant factors may differ)